# Macro to copy columns between files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy columns from one file into another but keep getting a runtime error. I think that the issue is with the file pathway. It is on a shared workstation but I have the files saved to my user desktop. Is there something I need to change with the file pathway? Thanks

```
Sub PlatingSheet()

Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("\\in-ge-file\users\tbever\Desktop\VBA\Plating 
Sheets\Copy - 24605_17 QC Results and Notes.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

Set targetColumn = Workbooks("\\in-ge-file\users\tbever\Desktop\VBA\Plating 
Sheets\Copy - 1.1Unified_Plating_Template.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub"
```

Answer (score 0):

Workbook's are referenced by their `Name` not there `FullName`.

```
Sub PlatingSheet()

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Copy - 24605_17 QC Results and Notes.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Copy - 1.1Unified_Plating_Template.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah gotcha, I think I was thinking too hard about the issue. Thanks.